# What is the correct place to add a CAGradientLayer in my custom table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table with custom table view cells. each table view cell has a background image plus some text on top of the image. I would like to add a gradient above the image view so that the text above the image is more easily readable.

Where is the CORRECT place to add this gradient?

I am currently adding this in cellForRowAtIndexPath, i'm pasting the code below.. the array cellShown keeps track of whether this cell was shown or not.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AirportPlaceListTableViewCell") as! AirportPlaceListTableViewCell
    cell.titleLabel.text = tableData[indexPath.row] as? String
    let imageName = tableImageData[indexPath.row] as? String
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName!)
    cell.placeImageView.image = TripnaryHelper.imageWithImage(image, scaledToSize: CGSizeMake(320, 320))

    if cellShown[indexPath.row] == false
    {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer.init()
        gradient.frame = cell.bounds
        let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, bottomColor.CGColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.66)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1.0)
        cell.placeImageView.layer .addSublayer(gradient)
        cellShown[indexPath.row] = true
    }

    return cell
}
```

what is happening here is that when the cells get reused, the gradient is getting added again. so my question is 
- how do I check for that?
- or, is there another place to add this gradient for my custom table view cell class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `CAGradientLayer` in your custom cell's (`AirportPlaceListTableViewCell`) overridden initialization method:

```
init(style style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier reuseIdentifier: String?)
```

However, if you have built your custom cell in a `xib`, then you'll want to add the `CAGradientLayer` after the `xib` has been loaded. In which case you can do it in `AirportPlaceListTableViewCell`'s:

```
func awakeFromNib()
```

Comment: thanks @simeon, that worked liked a charm. I added it to `func awakeFromNib()`